# Angular 4.4.4 project with sass styles : material design setup doesn't work

Tags: angular, intellij-idea, material-design

I've followed this guide(link in comments) to implement material components and icons in my angular 4 project.

I'm encountering and error when I try to import material design in my scss config file with these lines:

```
@import '~https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

IntelliJ alert me with :"Cannot find URL...etc"

Now I'm using a workaround importing directly in desider HTML file
the icons from material with this link:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

but like this all the step did in the tutorial are useless.

Can anyone say to me where i'm doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**
Removed `~` as requested:

[image: RESULT IMAGE]

I'm not very skilled in angular2 project structure ( my front-end co-worker got flu ).

I'm asking myself where to put these 2 lines , because i can't find in my project the global `style.css`

[image: PROJECT STRUCTURE PHOTO]

**FINAL EDIT**

Following the documentation tutorial from the beginning, worked for me.

I solved creating a custome theme, because material REQUIRE a theme to start the components.

For the icons-> just put the link import in index.html.

For Components-> follow the "[get started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)" part of the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading `~` from the URL: it's a webpack shorthand for `node_modules/`.

This is why they use it in the following line for angular/material: it's rewritten to `node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css`.

EDIT:

You can add that by following the tooltip (go into Settings > DTD and add it here as a URI):

[image]

Comment: Done, but now there is a warning, see for edited post , i'll link another image!

Comment: @Tommolo Ok! Please make sure you add it as a new section (after, say "EDIT:" so the original question is there for others with the same problem. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm a junior developer that just discovered the stackoverflow world : Post Edited!!!

Comment: @Tommolo Edited. See above.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable an inspection that is downloaded by your IDE. You can see how to do that

> [Disabling and Enabling Inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html)
>
> Disabling or enabling inspections To disable or enable an inspection
>   in the Settings/Preferences dialog
>
> ```
> Find the desired inspection, by expanding the grouping nodes or using the search field.
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> - Use the check box next to the inspection to disable or enable it.
> - Apply the changes and close the dialog box.

---

The way IJ uses inspections to validate the code against known error, these 
inspections are downloaded by IDE to your profile. Inspections not always give you correct results when a new features are used by the code. In this way you should either update the IDE or download/modify/suppress/disable an inspection. The code for CSS doesn't need to compile, it's transplited by the webpack or other packager in your application.

Comment: Why would you disable it? It seems like it's correctly surfacing an error since `node_modules/http://...` is very likely not the intended import target.

Comment: @msanford The inspection is outdated.

Comment: I'm still weary of disabling _all_ inspections of a given class; is there not a risk to lose valuable debugging information, even if it's not valid in this _specific_ case?